# Is there a callback for before loading a relationship in a has_many relationship or perhaps a Proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.2.18. This is a bit of a complex behavior but we have a has_many relationship say the following:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes

...


class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item  
  attr_accessor :body, :is_enabled
```

What I'd like to do is when a method does:

```
@note=Note.find(2)
```

the item object (or possibly the note object) can do a check before establishing the relationship. Specifically, in our body we have a bunch of content that must be checked for all the items to be valid (say we use a phrase like ITEM2, ITEM17 for item #2 or item #17). If any of the items are invalid, the the note should have is_enabled set to false and not be loaded. How can I check the validity of ITEM2 before the note is loaded? I was hoping for a callback or perhaps a condition which contains a macro like:

```
  has_many :notes, Proc.new { I don't know what to put here? }
```

Comment: When is the `:is_enabled` flag set on a Note instance?

Comment: on creation, would be set to is_enabled=true and if it fails validity checks, set it to false

Comment: Is that stored in the database then? Or always determined at load time?

Comment: stored in database, the validity of `:body` would be determined at load time

Comment: There's on-load type callbacks but they're bad to use because they happen way more than you want. Would it be acceptable to use an `after_add` callback? So that when you add a new `note` you determine and set the :is_enabled flag and then have your has_many (or a scope) weed out those that aren't enabled?

Comment: yeah, that's possible. I guess the crux of the matter is that I want to  be able to add validation rules on either the item or note side rather than having to do callbacks on the various classes affecting it. Since I wrote this question, I think it makes more sense to have a NoteBodyValidator class that has a class method like is valid such that I could call `NoteBodyValidator.check_body @note`; I THINK this might give me the best of both worlds in centralizing the rule set but also  being able to run the check dynamically. Sorry if that's a very roundabout note.

Answer (score 0):

Considering is_enabled flag is set in database, you may define multiple associations like:

```
has_many :notes #This will retrieve all notes
has_many :enabled_notes, :conditions => {:is_enabled => true}
```

Comment: thx, looking for someething that's a preloading validation though. I think for your above association you would want the second to have different name like `has_many :all_notes` or something